# Store a calculated math equation in a Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on this:

[image]

I would like to know how to create a new column that holds the amount equal to `LocalCurrency` multiplied by `ExchangeRate` for each rows of item.

Comment: Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: And please don't use images - format the sample data as text.

Comment: And if you don't need a column in your table, just in your result set, then just add the calculation. to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed column:

```
alter table t add newcolumn as (localcurrency * exchangerate);
```

This adds the column to the table so it is calculated automatically when you retrieve it.  The value is automatically set so no update is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate when required in a query or can create a view to do so and use it wherever required.

```
CREATE VIEW Purchase_details AS
SELECT *, localcurrencyamount*exchangerate
FROM your_table_name

Select * from Purchase_details
```